# Automatically adding letters of significance to a ggplot barplot using output from TukeyHSD

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, label, significance

Using this data...

```
hogs.sample<-structure(list(Zone = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Levelname = c("Medium", "High", 
"Low", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", 
"Med.High", "Medium", "Med.High", "Medium", "Med.High", "High", 
"Medium", "High", "Low", "Med.High", "Low", "High", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Med.High", "Low", "Low", "Med.High", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "High", "Med.High", "High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Medium", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "Med.High", "Low"), hogs.fit = c(-0.122, 
-0.871, -0.279, -0.446, 0.413, 0.011, 0.157, 0.131, 0.367, -0.23, 
0.007, 0.05, 0.04, -0.184, -0.265, -1.071, -0.223, 0.255, -0.635, 
-1.103, 0.008, -0.04, 0.831, 0.042, -0.005, -0.022, 0.692, 0.402, 
0.615, 0.785, 0.758, 0.738, 0.512, 0.222, -0.424, 0.556, -0.128, 
-0.495, 0.591, 0.923)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    Zone = c("B", "D"), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm trying to add letters of significance based on a Tukeys HSD to the plot below...

```
library(agricolae)
library(tidyverse)
hogs.plot <- ggplot(hogs.sample, aes(x = Zone, y = exp(hogs.fit), 
                                     fill = factor(Levelname, levels = c("High", "Med.High", "Medium", "Low")))) +  
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(0.9), color = "black") +  
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.2) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "CPUE (+/-1SE)", legend = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("midnightblue", "dodgerblue4", "steelblue3", 'lightskyblue')) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("B", "D"), labels=c("Econfina", "Steinhatchee"))+
  scale_color_hue(l=40, c = 100)+
 # coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 3.5)) +
  labs(title = "Hogs", x = "", legend = NULL) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(), axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none")
hogs.plot
```

My ideal output would be something like this...

[image]

I'm not sure if these letters are 100% accurate on my sample plot, but they signify which groups are significantly different from each other. Zones are independent, so I don't want any comparisons between the two zones so I was running them seperate with the following code.

```
hogs.aov.b <- aov(hogs.fit ~Levelname, data = filter(hogs.sample, Zone == "B"))
hogs.aov.summary.b <- summary(hogs.aov.b)
hogs.tukey.b <- TukeyHSD(hogs.aov.b)
hogs.tukey.b

hogs.aov.d <- aov(hogs.fit ~ Levelname, data = filter(hogs.sample, Zone == "D"))
hogs.aov.summary.d <- summary(hogs.aov.d)
hogs.tukey.d <- TukeyHSD(hogs.aov.d)
hogs.tukey.d
```

I tried this route but I have many species other than hogs to apply this to.
[Show statistically significant difference in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463301/show-statistically-significant-difference-in-a-graph)

I can get the letters for one zone at a time, but I'm not sure how to add both zones to the plot. They are also out of order. I modified this code from a webpage and the letters do not place atop the bars nicely.

```
library(agricolae)
library(tidyverse)
# get highest point overall
abs_max <- max(bass.dat.d$bass.fit)
# get the highest point for each class
maxs <- bass.dat.d %>%
  group_by(Levelname) %>%
  # I like to add a little bit to each value so it rests above
  # the highest point. Using a percentage of the highest point
  # overall makes this code a bit more general
  summarise(bass.fit=max(mean(exp(bass.fit))))
# get Tukey HSD results
Tukey_test <- aov(bass.fit ~ Levelname, data=bass.dat.d) %>%
  HSD.test("Levelname", group=TRUE) %>%
  .$groups %>%
  as_tibble(rownames="Levelname") %>%
  rename("Letters_Tukey"="groups") %>%
  select(-bass.fit) %>%
  # and join it to the max values we calculated -- these are
  # your new y-coordinates
  left_join(maxs, by="Levelname")
```

There are lots of examples like this too https://www.staringatr.com/3-the-grammar-of-graphics/bar-plots/3_tukeys/ but they all just add text manually. It would be nice to have code that can take the Tukey output and add the significance letter to the plot automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't understand your data/analysis (e.g. why do you use `exp()` on hogs.fit and what are the letters supposed to be?) so I'm not sure whether this is correct, but nobody else has answered so here is my best guess:

#### Correct example:

```r
## Source: Rosane Rech
## https://statdoe.com/cld-customisation/#adding-the-letters-indicating-significant-differences
## https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyof3S1gx3M

library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(multcompView)

# analysis of variance
anova <- aov(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts)

# Tukey's test
tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)

# compact letter display
cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey)

# table with factors and 3rd quantile
dt <- group_by(chickwts, feed) %>%
  summarise(w=mean(weight), sd = sd(weight)) %>%
  arrange(desc(w))

# extracting the compact letter display and adding to the Tk table
cld <- as.data.frame.list(cld$feed)
dt$cld <- cld$Letters

print(dt)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   feed          w    sd cld  
#>   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 sunflower  329.  48.8 a    
#> 2 casein     324.  64.4 a    
#> 3 meatmeal   277.  64.9 ab   
#> 4 soybean    246.  54.1 b    
#> 5 linseed    219.  52.2 bc   
#> 6 horsebean  160.  38.6 c

ggplot(dt, aes(feed, w)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = w), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = w-sd, ymax=w+sd), width = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "Feed Type", y = "Average Weight Gain (g)") +
  geom_text(aes(label = cld, y = w + sd), vjust = -0.5) +
  ylim(0,410) +
  theme_few()
```

[image]

#### My 'best guess' with your data:

```r
hogs.sample <- structure(list(Zone = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                       "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", 
                                       "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                       "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Levelname = c("Medium", "High", 
                                                                                    "Low", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Med.High", 
                                                                                    "Med.High", "Medium", "Med.High", "Medium", "Med.High", "High", 
                                                                                    "Medium", "High", "Low", "Med.High", "Low", "High", "Medium", 
                                                                                    "Medium", "Med.High", "Low", "Low", "Med.High", "Low", "Low", 
                                                                                    "High", "High", "Med.High", "High", "Med.High", "Med.High", "Medium", 
                                                                                    "High", "Low", "Low", "Med.High", "Low"), hogs.fit = c(-0.122, 
                                                                                                                                           -0.871, -0.279, -0.446, 0.413, 0.011, 0.157, 0.131, 0.367, -0.23, 
                                                                                                                                           0.007, 0.05, 0.04, -0.184, -0.265, -1.071, -0.223, 0.255, -0.635, 
                                                                                                                                           -1.103, 0.008, -0.04, 0.831, 0.042, -0.005, -0.022, 0.692, 0.402, 
                                                                                                                                           0.615, 0.785, 0.758, 0.738, 0.512, 0.222, -0.424, 0.556, -0.128, 
                                                                                                                                           -0.495, 0.591, 0.923)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                             Zone = c("B", "D"), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# anova
anova <- aov(hogs.fit ~ Levelname * Zone, data = hogs.sample)

# Tukey's test
tukey <- TukeyHSD(anova)

# compact letter display
cld <- multcompLetters4(anova, tukey)

# table with factors and 3rd quantile
dt <- hogs.sample %>% 
  group_by(Zone, Levelname) %>%
  summarise(w=mean(exp(hogs.fit)), sd = sd(exp(hogs.fit)) / sqrt(n())) %>%
  arrange(desc(w)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Levelname = factor(Levelname,
                            levels = c("High",
                                       "Med.High",
                                       "Medium",
                                       "Low"),
                            ordered = TRUE))

# extracting the compact letter display and adding to the Tk table
cld2 <- data.frame(letters = cld$`Levelname:Zone`$Letters)
dt$cld <- cld2$letters

print(dt)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   Zone  Levelname     w     sd cld  
#>   <chr> <ord>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 D     High      1.97  0.104  a    
#> 2 D     Med.High  1.69  0.206  ab   
#> 3 D     Low       1.36  0.258  abc  
#> 4 B     Med.High  1.14  0.0872 abc  
#> 5 B     Medium    0.875 0.0641 bcd  
#> 6 D     Medium    0.874 0.111  bcd  
#> 7 B     Low       0.696 0.0837 cd   
#> 8 B     High      0.481 0.118  d

ggplot(dt, aes(x = Levelname, y = w)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Levelname), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = w - sd, ymax = w + sd), width = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "Levelname", y = "Average hogs.fit") +
  geom_text(aes(label = cld, y = w + sd), vjust = -0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Zone)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Both examples not working as of 2023/01/23, probably due to apparent changes in group_by: Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Both examples work as of 14-12-2023 @nouse; not sure what the problem was but it appears to have been rectified. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 7):

I think I can extend on jared_mamrot's answer!

First, you'll find a reprex ready to be copy-pasted. Below, I have some additional comments on this.

### reprex

```r
hogs.sample <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Zone = c("B","B","B","B","B","B",
           "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
           "B","B","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D",
           "D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D"),
  Levelname = c("Medium","High","Low",
                "Med.High","Med.High","Med.High","Med.High","Med.High",
                "Med.High","Medium","Med.High","Medium","Med.High",
                "High","Medium","High","Low","Med.High","Low","High",
                "Medium","Medium","Med.High","Low","Low","Med.High",
                "Low","Low","High","High","Med.High","High",
                "Med.High","Med.High","Medium","High","Low","Low",
                "Med.High","Low"),
  hogs.fit = c(-0.122,-0.871,-0.279,-0.446,
               0.413,0.011,0.157,0.131,0.367,-0.23,0.007,0.05,
               0.04,-0.184,-0.265,-1.071,-0.223,0.255,-0.635,
               -1.103,0.008,-0.04,0.831,0.042,-0.005,-0.022,0.692,
               0.402,0.615,0.785,0.758,0.738,0.512,0.222,-0.424,
               0.556,-0.128,-0.495,0.591,0.923)
)

library(tidyverse)

# {emmeans}, {multcomp} & {multcompView} ----------------------------------
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

# set up model
model <- lm(exp(hogs.fit) ~ Levelname * Zone, data = hogs.sample)

# get (adjusted) means
model_means <- emmeans(object = model,
                       specs = ~ Levelname | Zone) 

# add letters to each mean
model_means_cld <- cld(object = model_means,
                       adjust = "Tukey",
                       Letters = letters,
                       alpha = 0.05)
# show output
model_means_cld
#> Zone = B:
#>  Levelname emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  High       0.481 0.199 32  -0.0445     1.01  a    
#>  Low        0.696 0.230 32   0.0884     1.30  ab   
#>  Medium     0.875 0.199 32   0.3488     1.40  ab   
#>  Med.High   1.139 0.133 32   0.7889     1.49   b   
#> 
#> Zone = D:
#>  Levelname emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  Medium     0.874 0.230 32   0.2673     1.48  a    
#>  Low        1.362 0.151 32   0.9650     1.76  ab   
#>  Med.High   1.688 0.163 32   1.2592     2.12   b   
#>  High       1.969 0.199 32   1.4436     2.50   b   
#> 
#> Results are given on the exp (not the response) scale. 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 4 estimates 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 

# format output for ggplot
model_means_cld <- model_means_cld %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Zone = case_when(
    Zone == "B" ~ "Econfina",
    Zone == "D" ~ "Steinhatchee"
  ))

# get ggplot
ggplot(data = model_means_cld,
       aes(x = Levelname, y = emmean, fill = Levelname)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Zone)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean - SE, ymax = emmean + SE), width = 0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "CPUE (adj. mean ± 1 std. error)",
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)),
    labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1)
  ) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  labs(title = "Hogs",
       caption = "Separaetly per Zone, means followed by a common letter are not significantly different according to the Tukey-test") +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_trim(.group), y = emmean + SE), vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("midnightblue", "dodgerblue4", "steelblue3", 'lightskyblue')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8)
  ) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Comments

- [This chapter](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/DSFAIR/compactletterdisplay.html) on using the compact letter display may be of interest to you. Note that it especially goes into why I put the caption below the ggplot.
- Furthermore, I believe that jared_mamrot changed one important thing compared to what you asked for. You have the option to either compare all 8 means to each other or compare all 4 Levelname means to each other separately per Zone. From the looks of the plot you showed you chose the second option and I reproduced it here via the `specs = ~ Levelname | Zone` in `emmeans()`. You can choose option 1 and find the same letters jared_mamrot found by changing this to `specs = ~ Levelname * Zone`. Both options are valid, but the results differ and you have to choose what you want. **EDIT:** I went into quite some detail on this in [this more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854552/any-other-options-besides-the-traditional-cld-bar-graph/70863531#70863531).
- Finally note that there is no need to separately calculate arithmetic means per factor level (combination) if you are using a function (like `emmeans()`) to comupute and compare those means to each other anyway. Moreover, in more complex cases with e.g. missing data, you should not show those simple arithmetics means and their standard error, but directly go for the estimated marginal means a.k.a. least squares means a.k.a. adjusted means a.k.a. model based means. In the simple case, however, they are identical to simple arithmetic means.