# ggeffects: Add post-hoc test letters doesn't mach in x position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add the significance letters to a plot using `ggeffects` package. In my case:

```
# Packages
library(ggeffects)
library(dplyr)
library(glmmTMB)
library(multcomp)
library(lsmeans)
library(ggplot2)

# My data set
ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/temp_ger_ds.csv")
str(ds)
#'data.frame':  140 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ temp       : chr  "constante" "constante" "constante" "constante" ...
# $ generation : chr  "G0" "G0" "G0" "G0" ...
# $ development: int  22 24 22 27 27 24 25 26 27 18 ...
```

General model:

```
mTCFd <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp * generation, data = ds,
               family = ziGamma(link = "log"))
```

3 combinations plot:

```
#1) Plot for temp
    lsm.mTCFd.temp <- lsmeans(mTCFd, c("temp"))
    lt<-cld(lsm.mTCFd.temp, Letters=letters, decreasing = TRUE)
    ds <- ds %>% mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(generation)-2)*0.05, 
                        group = generation)
    df_gg <-ggpredict(mTCFd, terms = c("temp"))%>% 
      mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(as.character(group))-2)*0.05)
    df_gg %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + 
      geom_text(aes(x = x_1, label = lt[,7]), vjust = -0.5, show.legend = FALSE) 

#2) Plot for generation
    lsm.mTCFd.gera <- lsmeans(mTCFd, c("generation"))
    lt<-cld(lsm.mTCFd.gera, Letters=letters, decreasing = TRUE)
    ds <- ds %>% mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(generation)-2)*0.05, 
                        group = generation)
    df_gg <-ggpredict(mTCFd, terms = c("generation"))%>% 
      mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(as.character(group))-2)*0.05)
    df_gg %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + 
      geom_text(aes(x = x_1, label = lt[,7]), vjust = -0.5, show.legend = FALSE) 

#3) Plot for temp and generation interaction

    lsm.mTCFd.temp.gera <- lsmeans(mTCFd, c("temp","generation"))
    lt<-cld(lsm.mTCFd.temp.gera , Letters=letters, decreasing = TRUE)
    ds <- ds %>% mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(generation)-2)*0.05, 
                        group = generation)
    df_gg <-ggpredict(mTCFd, terms = c("temp","generation"))%>% 
      mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(as.character(group))-2)*0.05)
    df_gg %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + 
      geom_text(aes(x = x_1, label = lt[,8]), vjust = -0.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

But I always as output:

```
Raw data not available.
Error in if (attr(x, "logistic", exact = TRUE) == "1" && attr(x, "is.trial",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is a reprex that takes your and [@Daniel's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73259673/8830099) as its basis and simply moves the letters to the position you want. I only replaced {lsmeans} with its successor {emmeans} and edited the `geom_text()` argument a bit - thus, I did not have a closer look at what is actually done.

However, I suggest you read my answers to similar questions in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69616158/8830099) and with even more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863531/8830099) on specifically dealing with 2-way interactions emmeans. Both of them will also point you to [this summary on compact letter displays](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html). I hope this helps.

```r
# Packages
library(ggeffects)
library(dplyr)
library(glmmTMB)
library(multcomp)
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)

# My data set
ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/temp_ger_ds.csv")

# General Model
mTCFd <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp * generation,
                 data = ds,
                 family = ziGamma(link = "log"))

lsm.mTCFd.temp <- emmeans(mTCFd, c("temp"))
#> NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
lt <- cld(lsm.mTCFd.temp, Letters = letters, decreasing = TRUE)
ds <- ds %>% 
  mutate(x_1 =  1 + (readr::parse_number(generation) - 2) * 0.05, group = generation)

# new lines, replace "mutate()" here
df_gg <- ggpredict(mTCFd, terms = c("temp"))
df_gg$x_1 <-
  1 + (readr::parse_number(as.character(df_gg$group)) - 2) * 0.05

df_gg %>% 
  plot(add.data = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, label = lt[, 7]),
            position = position_nudge(x = 0.1),
            show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think the code that is not working is `mutate()`, which drops all attributes from the data frame. This one works for me, when you replace the code-line that contains `mutate()`:

```r
lsm.mTCFd.temp <- lsmeans(mTCFd, c("temp"))
lt<-cld(lsm.mTCFd.temp, Letters=letters, decreasing = TRUE)
ds <- ds %>% mutate(x_1=  1+(readr::parse_number(generation)-2)*0.05, 
                    group = generation)

# new lines, replace "mutate()" here
df_gg <-ggpredict(mTCFd, terms = c("temp"))
df_gg$x_1 <- 1+(readr::parse_number(as.character(df_gg$group))-2)*0.05

df_gg %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = x_1, label = lt[,7]), vjust = -0.5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice Daniel, but the "a" and "b" letter is inside the same level, and I need the letter "a" in "constante" and "b" in "flutuante".